# insert jquery variable into html input

Tags: jquery

Aim is to get value from one input cell and insert to another.

To get value I use

```
var name = $('#test').val();
```

And the above works.

Then I need to insert. If I insert simple text (not variable), then it works

```
$("#test3").val("Dolly Duck");
```

**But how to insert variable (var name) instead of val("Dolly Duck")?**

Below if whole code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//This works
$("#btn3").click(function(){
$("#test3").val("Dolly Duck");
});

//But his does not work
//at first get value from input form (define variable) and alert to check if it works
var name = $('#test').val();
//alert(name);

//now need to insert
//$("#btn4").click(function(){

//below does not work None of them
//$("#test").name;
//$("#test4").$('#test').val();
//$("#test4").jsvar: $('#test').val();

});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test" value="Mickey Mouse1"></p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test3" value="Mickey Mouse2"></p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test4" value="Mickey Mouse3"></p>
<button id="btn1">Show Value</button>
<button id="btn3">Set Value</button>
<button id="btn4">Set Value</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("#test").val(varName);` ?

Comment: Unfortunately $("#test").val(varName); does not work. Working example is accepted answer.

Comment: I guess I should have made it more clear that you were supposed to replace varName with your variable name (which happens to be `name`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the variable:

```
$("#test3").val(name);
```

I would also fetch the value right before you want to set the value of the other textbox, as the `name` variable won't update by itself:

```
$("#btn3").click(function() {
    var name = $('#test').val();
    $("#test3").val(name);
});
```

Also, make sure that your code that interacts with the DOM is inside of a `$(document).ready()` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn3").click(function() {
        var name = $('#test').val();
        $("#test3").val(name);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. As I understand I can define multiple $(document).ready(function() in one file? Now used two and all works....

Comment: @user2232696: You can, but I wouldn't do it.

Comment: Thanks. But in such case.. you wrote: fetch the value right before you want to set the value of the other textbox. The textbox is within <body></body> but in <head></head> I need to call other functions within document ready... Not fully understand: name variable won't update by itself: If in <head></head> I define variable name, then latter the variable may be unset (disappear/change)? For what reasons?

Comment: @user2232696: Well, if you change the textbox's value afterwards, `name` won't reflect that change, as you grabbed the value at the very beginning.